# Php rate limit doesn't work with curl requests

Tags: php, http, curl

I took this function to limit http requests surfing on internet:

```
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_CALL'])) {
    $last = strtotime($_SESSION['LAST_CALL']);
    $curr = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
    $sec =  abs($last - $curr);
    if ($sec <= 2) {
      die('Rate Limit Exceeded');  // rate limit   
    }
  }
  $_SESSION['LAST_CALL'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

It works with browser

[image: with browser]

but if I try a request with curl:

```
curl http://localhost/project/p.php
```

[image: curl]
Nothing happens

How can I update this in order to make rate limit valid for curl too?

**SOLUTION**

I check if cookies are accepted by the client, if no exit:

```
setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600);
if(count($_COOKIE) == 0){
     die ("Cookie Not Enabled");
}
```

to make a curl request with cookies a save a cookie file and then I make another request with cookies:

```
curl http://localhost/project/p.php -c cookie-jar.txt

curl http://localhost/project/register.php --cookie "PHPSESSID=g90tqc0hvp6sodods9jisss912"
```

Comment: Sessions require cookies to work, so you need to store the rate information somewhere other than `$_SESSION` if you want to rate-limit clients that don't support cookies.

Comment: So I can add in php a function that checks if client accept cookies? And how can I set the accepting of cookies with curl?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I check if cookies are accepted by the client, if no exit:

```
setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600);
if(count($_COOKIE) == 0){
     die ("Cookie Not Enabled");
}
```

to make a curl request with cookies a save a cookie file and then I make another request with cookies:

```
curl http://localhost/project/p.php -c cookie-jar.txt

curl http://localhost/project/register.php --cookie "PHPSESSID=g90tqc0hvp6sodods9jisss912"
```